# Convert future date to UTC

Tags: solidity

Is there an easy way to convert a set time to UTC and stored in a smart contract?
I know we can set dates relative to the current timestamp such as "`now + 5 days`".
Though if we wanted to set a variable to a specific date, how could we do this? without having to convert the date to UTC off chain

sorry if its a repeat question, didn't see anything like it which i thought was odd..

Comment: I don't see why you'd ever need something like that. It's very inefficient in my opinion in terms of storage and gas costs. If you need to do this for the UI, you could instead keep the on-chain timestamps and use a service like The Graph to translate data into other formats (timestamp -> date, IPFS hash -> text content, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Current time on the Ethereum blockchain can be retrieved using `now` which returns the unix timestamp for the current block.

So if you want something to check if the current block was greater than a certain date, you would first get the unix timestamp for that date, and then compare `now` to that date.

```
uint date = 1546300800
```

This would make `date` represent `Tue 01 Jan 2019 12:00:00 AM UTC`.

Comment: I meant, how can i get the unix timestamp for a date (not the current block) from within solidarity / the chain. for example, 01 Jan 2019 12:00:00 AM UTC

Comment: I do not believe this is a function made available in solidity. To computers, unix is time, and that is all they need. Things like `days`, `weeks`, `years` are just [literal numbers](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=time#time-units) representing time in seconds. Note that the blockchain has no concept of months or a calendar format.